# Bootstrap responsive table disappears

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a responsive table but my table disappears in wide window and I can't understand why. My code is here, the line table responsive is commented so it works on wide screens and it is for me to see the table:

```
    <!DOCKTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
            <title>WebHosting-Preços</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!--NavBar-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">WebHosting</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li><a href="contactos.html">Contactos</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="preços.html">Preços</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div><!--NavBar END-->
            <div class="columns2">
                <ul class="price">
                    <li class="header">Host</li>
                    <li class="grey">Free</li>
                    <li>Sem criação de WebSite</li>
                    <li>Sem Dominio</li>
                    <li class="grey"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="precos" role="button">Buy Now</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="columns2">
                <ul class="price">
                    <li class="header">Host + WebSite</li>
                    <li class="grey">€ 9.99</li>
                    <li>Criação do WebSite</li>
                    <li>Sem Dominio</li>
                    <li class="grey"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="precos" role="button">Buy Now</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="columns2">
                <ul class="price">
                    <li class="header">Host + WebSite + Dominio</li>
                    <li class="grey">€ 9.99 / year</li>
                    <li>Criação do WebSite</li>
                    <li>Dominio incluido</li>
                    <li class="grey"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="precos" role="button">Buy Now</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Serviço</th>
                        <th>Descrição</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Criação de website</td>
                        <td>A Empresa responsabiliza-se pela criação de um website a seu gosto</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Dominio</td>
                        <td>A Empresa responsabiliza-se pela compra e manutenção do Dominio escolhido pelo utilizador</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
    body { 
        margin: 0;
    }
    .jumbotron{
        align-items:center;
        display:flex;
        background-image:url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/392018/pexels-photo-392018.jpeg');
        background-size:cover;
        height:450px;
        color:white;
        height: 50vh;
    }
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .columns {
        float: left;
        width: 33.3%;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    .columns2 {
        float: left;
        width: 33.3%;
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
    .price {
        list-style-type: none;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    .price:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
    }
    .price .header {
        background-color: #2D2727;
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .price li {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .price .grey {
        background-color: #eee;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .button {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .columns {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    .table{
        color: black;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .table th{
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: i cannot replicate the problem see here > https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/34056/  what bootstrap are you using ?

Comment: did you corectly include bootstrap? how did you include it?

Comment: I will edit my post and paste all the code

Comment: hmmm... i copied your code and it works in my case... altho i recomend you copy the scripts at the end of the body page...
What does your console show when the table is not apearing?

Comment: What do you mean by my console? I'm doing this on notepad ++ and running it on chrome

Comment: right click > inspect element > and at the bottom of the browser a console will open where you can see the code and sort of debug problem or change css

Comment: Ok I got the problem, It is only responsive, so it only works on small screens. Wide window doesn't work and on a small window works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be .table-responsive class inherit or override in your css or any other css/library override it.

But I tried below example with table-responsive class it is working fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
                                                                            
  <div class="table-responsive">          
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
        <th>Column 5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>324</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was working just fine, but if I delete the h2 the table dissapears again

Comment: I removed <h2> tag from this code but still it is working. Please have a look on it.

Comment: I already found the problem and I answered my own answer, but I can only approve it on 2 days

Comment: @SamuelFerreira this solution solved your problem? Please confirm

Answer (score 1):

it might be helpful.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-responsive class creates a responsive table which will scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, there is no difference:</p>                                                                                      
  <div class="table-responsive">          
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Anna</td>
        <td>Pitt</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>USA</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that on this part:

```
<div class="container">                                                                                 
    <div class="table-responsive">          
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Serviços</th>
                    <th>Descrição</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

It only says the table to be responsive and not both a normal table and a responsive table, in order to change it I needed to do this:

```
<div class="table table-responsive">
```

instead of

```
<div class="table-responsive">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` just above your table HTML, CSS of elements above your table code is inhering its properties to the table elements